# Changing layout/css of product detail page dynamically

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am in a situation where I need to have a different layout for a specific Product Type.
It'll be okay if I could load a different CSS for this Product Type.

Is anything like this possible through code/xml?

I am able to identify the product type in `catalog/product/view.phtml`, will it be  helpful?
I also noticed a node in `catalog.xml` named `<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>` or `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>` etc.
will something like this help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is a valid one, something like this should be possible:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/your_file.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Take a look at `page.xml` to see what other sorts of tricks the same block can perform.

Comment: amazing, I have been seeing your answers across all the Magento questions.. glad to have heard with you. I just try that out and post back

Comment: I'm an addict. I try to limit myself to one answer a day ;)

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried to add <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/test.css</stylesheet></action> but to no avail, sorry, I am sort of a beginner in Magento, and thus may not be very efficient in looking what files does what :-/

Comment: NO!! Don't limit yourself in such a way.. what will happen to us noobs then!? :-P

Comment: By the way, I am working with Unirgy_giftcert, and would want to modify things when the product type is `ugiftcert`

Comment: I can't think what is wrong with this approach. Where did you make the change and did you remember to clear caches afterwards? Also make sure CSS files are not being merged, that would only confuse debugging.

Comment: I have disabled caching so that I see the changes instantly, will enable them once the site goes live. I replicated one of the lines in `catalog.xml` which was adding a CSS somewhere,; added a dummy file `test.css` to see if it gets included. nothing happened. I had modified modern theme to suit my templating needs. didn't do anything in page.xml for this, though

Comment: Damn on me.. it works now. I was messing up with the path. thanks @clockworkgeek, whatever you answered worked like a charm! thanks a lot! :)  Here's +15 to your huge rep

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at `catalog.xml` not `page.xml` for **product type**.
This is if you are using **magento 1.7** and up.